# Sidekiq's Delayed Extensions will be removed in Sidekiq 7.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

I'm running:

- ruby 3.1.1
- Rails 7.0.2.3
- Sidekiq 6.4.1

I was upgrading from earlier versions of the bunch and I have this line of code in initializers/sidekiq.rb

```
Sidekiq::Extensions.enable_delay!
```

I get a warning message saying

> config/initializers/sidekiq.rb:3: warning: Sidekiq's Delayed Extensions will be removed in Sidekiq 7.0

However I couldn't find what to do. How to replace the functionality provided by Delayed Extensions. I'm currently using it just for emails.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Starting in Sidekiq version 5, they disabled the delayed extensions by default, with their [reasoning documented here](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/pull/3299). Due to their flexibility, they were prone to misuse.If all you were using the delayed extensions for was to run a job in the future, there are two replacements you can use.

Sidekiq's way to handle this is called [Scheduled Jobs](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Scheduled-Jobs), which looks a bit like `SomeSidekiqWorker.perform_in(3.hours, 'argument 1', 'argument 2')`, or if you have a specific time you'd like the job to execute, `perform_at`.

This functionality is also now built into ActiveJob ([Rails guide](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html#enqueue-the-job), [API documentation](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveJob/Core/ClassMethods.html#method-i-set)), and looks like `SomeJob.set(wait: 3.hours).perform_later('argument 1', 'argument 2')`.

The simplest option with a standard rails mailer would be something like these, which use the ActiveJob mechanism under the hood ([API Documentation](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/MessageDelivery.html#method-i-deliver_later)).

```
WelcomeMailer.welcome(User.first).deliver_later(wait: 3.hours)
WelcomeMailer.welcome(User.first).deliver_later(wait_until: 3.hours.from_now)
```

Answer (score 3):

They are moving to a 3rd party gem. https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/5076